# ActionBar is not showing items

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I am trying to customize the `ActionBar` so that I can add item named "scan", when i run the below code nothing appears on the `ActionBar`.

please let me know how to do that correctly.

**update**:

my Activity extends AvtionBarActivity

**code**:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.itemDiscover).setVisible(true);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item 
    android:id="@+id/itemDiscover"
    android:title="Scan"
    android:icon="@drawable/fr"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

**style.xml**:

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and add extra `xmlns` attribute for your menu and try `app:showAsAction` instead of `android:showAsAction`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

      <item 
          android:id="@+id/itemDiscover"
          android:title="Scan"
          android:icon="@drawable/fr"
          app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: try to add this xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" as i have given in answer

Comment: i tried it, it gives an error saying:menu item should specify title

Answer (score 0):

Change menu.xml with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item 
    android:id="@+id/itemDiscover"
    android:title="Scan"
    android:icon="@drawable/fr"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: this is correct way to write menu.xml file check this link http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html